# InterfaceFileForASetTemplateClass

Tags: c++, interface

InterfaceFileForASetTemplateClass

Hi stackoverflow.com forum people,
I've typed up this code direct from the text book, Absolute C++ Fourth Edition Savitch ISBN-13: 978-0-13-136584-1.

Interface File For A Set Template Class page 808.

`sort.cpp` on page 782 gives the error on line 13:

```
Line 13 error: expected initializer before numeric constant
```

Could someone help as I would expect the text book to 'just work' so I can study the code and not get stuck on extra errors I don't understand.

```
//This is the implementation file listtools.cpp. This file contains
//function definitions for the functions declared in listtools.h.
#include <cstddef>
#include "listtools.h"
namespace LinkedListSavitch
{
    template<class T>
    void headInsert(Node<T>*& head, const T& theData)
    {
        head = new Node<T>(theData, head);
    }
    template<class T>
    void insert(Node<T>* afterMe, const T& theData)12
    {
        afterMe->setLink(new Node<T>(theData, afterMe->getLink()));
    }
    template<class T>
    void deleteNode(Node<T>* before)
    {
        Node<T> *discard;
        discard = before->getLink();
        before->setLink(discard->getLink());
        delete discard;
    }
    template<class T>
    void deleteFirstNode(Node<T>*& head)
    {
        Node<T> *discard;
        discard = head;
        head = head->getLink();
        delete discard;
    }
    //Uses cstddef:
    template<class T>
    Node<T>* search(Node<T>* head, const T& target)
    {
        Node<T>* here = head;
        if (here == NULL) //if empty list
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            while (here->getData() != target && here->getLink() != NULL)
                here = here->getLink();
            if (here->getData() == target)
                return here;
            else
                return NULL;
        }
    }
}//LinkedListSavitch
```

Comment: Don't let us hanging! Please do tell us, is the `12` present at the book or not?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `12` on line 13, is that really on the book? A serious oversight if it is. Just remove it, and your code should work.

Comment: Thank you K-ballo. This seems to indeed be an error in the text book then.